# Why does __inbyte crash my software?

Tags: c++, intrinsics

I came across this function and I wanted to know what does it do, so I wrote the following, compiled with mingw32 and executed under Wine and Windows, on both of which the program crashed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <intrin.h>
int main()
{
 unsigned char j = __inbyte(0xABC); // example value
 printf("%i\n", j);
 return 0;
}
```

I've looked it up on MSDN, but I find the description to be vague.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/732t2y37%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

unsigned char __inbyte(unsigned short Port);

Generates the **in** instruction, returning one byte read from the port specified by Port.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The IN instruction attempts to directly read a byte from a CPU I/O port. This is a privileged operation, and will (almost) always fail unless you're in supervisor mode (e.g, in the kernel).

Unless you plan on writing kernel drivers, you can safely forget that you ever saw this intrinsic.

Comment: And even if you're writing a driver, there are typically OS routines for performing this kind of operation in a architecture independent way.

Comment: Right — outside of a few platform devices which already have drivers, most devices you'd be likely to write a driver for are accessed over PCI/PCIe/USB, not direct I/O ports.